# In Django ORM, A "Student - Course" Model design

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-views, pinax

I would like to design a model for an online private school in Django. It focuses on relation among `Students`, `Tutors` and `Courses`.

The most important factor that should be considered is that `Students` can add and `Tutors` can create courses.

I'd like to extend built-in Djano's "User" and extend its functionality.

I have designed a very draft model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User , Group
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    description = models.TextField()
    student = models.ManyToManyField('Student' , null = True, blank = True, related_name = _('Student courses'))
    tutor = models.ManyToManyField('Tutor' , null = True, blank = True , related_name = _('Tutor courses'))


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('course')
        verbose_name_plural = ('courses')


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , blank = True)
    #photo = models.ImageField(_('photo'), upload_to='photos/', blank=True)



class Tutor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , blank = True)
    #photo = models.ImageField(_('photo'), upload_to='photos/', blank=True)
```

First of all: is it a correct approach? I'd like to have User, so I can use it in View and Template layers.

Second, how can I query that which student has got which courses?

Thank you beforehand ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have a `Student` and `Tutor` model I would look at using the [user profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) supported by Django. Also the auth module has a fairly complete [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions) model, that you could use instead of creating your own system to allow only some users to create courses.

Comment: Thanks cberner. Do you recommend this over Proxy Model? I have to add some fields to Student and Tutors, beside ordinary Django User fields.

Answer (score 4):

As @cberner says, you should look into user profiles. At the end of the day you want both the students and tutors be true-blue `User`s so you can access them from the request, after they're logged in.

That being said, there's still some merit in having separate models, as long as those are *proxy* models. You can think of proxy models as a type of alias. They can't add additional fields to the database, but they can have their own unique methods, managers, etc. For example:

```
class Student(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Student: %s' % super(Student, self).__unicode__()
```

That's a very basic example, but it's meant to illustrate that even though this is still a `User` as far as the database is concerned, you can override and add methods that make it unique in its own right.

Of course, though, you'll need some way to differentiate a `Student` from a `Tutor` and even a regular old `User`. I find groups to be the best way to accomplish this for `User` proxies. For example, you can create "Student" and "Tutor" groups and then any user assigned to the "Student" group, for example, can be obtained through the `Student` model.

```
class StudentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.filter(groups__name='Student')

class Student(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.groups.filter(name='Student').exists():
            group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create('Student')
            self.groups.add(group)
```

That assures that any time you create a `Student`, it's automatically added to the "Student" group, and if you retrieve objects with `Student` (e.g. `Student.objects.all()`), you only get `User`s that belong to the "Student" group.

Because these are separate models, you can also reference them individually in the admin, so you can have a separate changelist and change form for a `Student`, for a `Tutor`, and for a regular `User`, if you want.

Assigning them to groups also makes it very easy to restrict parts of the admin. For example, since only `Tutor`s should be able to create, change or delete courses you can add the following methods to your `CourseAdmin`:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='Tutor').exists()

def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='Tutor').exists()

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='Tutor').exists()
```

And only superusers or members of the "Tutor" group will be able to add a brand new or change or delete an existing course.

Comment: This a mind-blowing response .. a Big High Five..
But I still wonder if for accessing Student's first_name , I should query "Student.course" or "User.course" ?
And specially, I should link the Course to Student by a ManyToManyField (direct or with "through" table), and the same for Tutor .. Right ??

Comment: It doesn't matter. `Student` is just an alias for `User`, so whether your instance is a `Student` or a `User`, `instance.course` will get you what you want. `Course` should be an M2M relationship (Student/tutors have many course and courses have many students and perhaps tutors). However, your `ManyToManyField` should be on `Course` and it should point to `User`. That covers both students and tutors.

Comment: Great, but consider that we want to connect a student to a school. I should add some extra fields to Students as well. Well, I also have to keep track of student activities!! So I have to link students to other tables. 
Is it feasible to have all of these with Proxy Models ??

Comment: humm.. What about tricking the relationship? Say, We have a Department Model with "student = Models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='student')"  field ??

Comment: Sure. In fact, if you end up needing multiple foreign key's to `User` you'd have to give each a unique related name anyways. Also, bear in mind that you can still directly create a relationship to the proxy models, ie. `ForeignKey(Student)`. Just be aware that if you do that, you can't store a generic `User` in that field; it must be a true `Student` instance.

Comment: Awesome .. I'll give it a try definitely